# How to make a select accent-insensitive via PHP form?

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, case-insensitive, non-ascii-characters

I tried finding something similar to my problem, but I always find the opposite situation...

Here's the deal (any help is greatly appreciated):

My database (innodb) is set to UTF8. Basically everything (server-side, client-side, database, connection, etc) is set to UTF8 and UTF8 general_ci collation...

What I understand is that the general_ci makes it case-insensitive but also makes accent-insensitive.

While in phpmyadmin, querying something like 'a' = 'á' results in true ("1"), trying to query a name with accent from a php form from another site simply results in "0".

Question is, how do I perform a select via php form which makes everything insensitive (like melee = mélee, jose = JOSÉ, etc)?

Everything is set to UTF8, including php headers, "SET NAMES ('utf8') and all those are set in my.cnf....
I also have a " accept-charset="utf-8" " in my form tag, but this is how it works:
- "jose" gives me only "jose%" entries...
- if I wanted to find JOSÉ, I can't simply query "jose", the last É "must" be exactly that uppercase with the accent (like josÉ or JOSÉ), but won't find anything if I try selecting "josé"....

They are all in utf8_general_ci, "show variables like '%character%'" brings me all UTF8...

The names are stored correctly in the database (with the UTF8 chars, and while viewing in a page, the values are displayed correctly), I can compare "a" and "Ã" via SQL in phpmyadmin with no problem, they return true... It just won't work when I use a form and a connection to that database... Letters are case-insensitive, right, but the accents are not (not even case-insensitive), any idea why is that?

How should my php form be in order to "send" both case AND accent insensitive strings?

Comment: Did you only run `SET NAMES('utf8')`? Try running `SET NAMES 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci';`

Comment: When you're connecting to the database in PHP, make sure you use either mysqli_set_charset or mysql_set_charset e.g. `mysqli_set_charset($link, "utf8");`

Comment: good suggestions, gonna try both then I'll post it here... thanks!

Comment: @Chris well, that didn't work... I tried placing the full "collate" but no dice...

Comment: @Craig tried that as well, but no deal... I tried placing either line in my connection, but they all bring the chars as if I was seeing in Latin1 (e.g.: André shows up AndrÃ©, can't find it by typing 'andre' or 'andré'/'André', only by 'Andr%'...)

Comment: should I place `mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci'");` or `mysql_set_charset('utf8', $conn);` somewhere in my form file?

Comment: Odd. Here's an excerpt from the documentation: Non-UCA collations have a one-to-one mapping from character code to weight. In MySQL, such collations are case insensitive and accent insensitive. utf8_general_ci is an example: 'a', 'A', 'À', and 'á' each have different character codes but all have a weight of 0x0041 and compare as equal.

Answer (score -1):

Here are some general all around things that might be causing it:

1. Just to be sure, you should be storing the current connection (the result of mysql_connect) and then you should be passing it as an argument to the mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'",$conn_handler);
2. Your database is UTF8, but what about your tables and columns? Are they UTF8 too?
3. Your views are encoded with UTF8 without BOM? This might cause that you're seeing the "Ã©" characters in "André".

If neither works, do you mind sharing the way you're connecting to the database?

Cheers!

Comment: thanks for the tips... you, the tables and columns are UTF8... Just not sure what "BOM" is (kinda new to databases)...

Comment: BOM is Byte Order Mark. It's not related to your database, but to your PHP script (the file itself). The file that "echoes" the variable should be saved as UTF-8 without BOM. Try using Notepad++. Cheers!

Comment: where can I get notepad++ for mac? I'm using Smultron atm but it only shows me an option to save as "UTF-8" but no other choices (with/without BOM)

Comment: just did a lil research, it says that os X related apps save UTF-8 without BOM...